# pyTorch can backward twice without setting retain_graph=True

Tags: pytorch, autograd

As indicated in [pyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/autograd_tutorial.html?highlight=retain_graph),

> if you even want to do the backward on some part of the graph twice,
>   you need to pass in retain_graph = True during the first pass.

However, I found the following codes snippet actually worked without doing so. I'm using pyTorch-0.4

```
x = torch.ones(2, 2, requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
y.backward(torch.ones(2, 2)) # Note I do not set retain_graph=True
y.backward(torch.ones(2, 2)) # But it can still work!
print x.grad
```

output:

```
tensor([[ 2.,  2.], 
        [ 2.,  2.]])
```

Could anyone explain? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why it works w/o `retain_graph=True` in your case is you have very simple graph that probably would have no internal intermediate buffers, in turn no buffers will be freed, so no need to use `retain_graph=True`.

But everything is changing when adding one more extra computation to your graph:

Code:

```py
x = torch.ones(2, 2, requires_grad=True)
v = x.pow(3)
y = v + 2

y.backward(torch.ones(2, 2))

print('Backward 1st time w/o retain')
print('x.grad:', x.grad)

print('Backward 2nd time w/o retain')

try:
    y.backward(torch.ones(2, 2))
except RuntimeError as err:
    print(err)

print('x.grad:', x.grad)
```

Output:

```py
Backward 1st time w/o retain
x.grad: tensor([[3., 3.],
                [3., 3.]])
Backward 2nd time w/o retain
Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.
x.grad: tensor([[3., 3.],
                [3., 3.]]).
```

In this case additional internal `v.grad` will be computed, but `torch` doesn't store intermediate values (intermediate gradients etc), and with `retain_graph=False` `v.grad` will be freed after first `backward`.

So, if you want to backprop second time you need to specify `retain_graph=True` to "keep" the graph.

Code:

```py
x = torch.ones(2, 2, requires_grad=True)
v = x.pow(3)
y = v + 2

y.backward(torch.ones(2, 2), retain_graph=True)

print('Backward 1st time w/ retain')
print('x.grad:', x.grad)

print('Backward 2nd time w/ retain')

try:
    y.backward(torch.ones(2, 2))
except RuntimeError as err:
    print(err)
print('x.grad:', x.grad)
```

Output:

```py
Backward 1st time w/ retain
x.grad: tensor([[3., 3.],
                [3., 3.]])
Backward 2nd time w/ retain
x.grad: tensor([[6., 6.],
                [6., 6.]])
```